# 70's time travel movie identification

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking for a movie that is not on any typical time travel list. It has a teenage girl (long hair in bell bottoms) who travels back in time and meets a teenage girl who ends up being her mother. They are sitting in a diner and the mom is eating a sandwich. That's all I've got.

Comment: Do you remember when or where you saw the movie? I know you've said 70s, but sometimes when/where you saw it can be helpful too.

Comment: Also language/country of origin. Even the smallest detail could help, so please be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 11):

It's early 80s, but could it be *[My Mother Was Never a Kid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Mother_Was_Never_a_Kid)*, based on Francine Pascal's *Hangin' Out With CiCi*? It involves a teenage girl going back in time and meeting her teenaged mother-to-be.

I would not describe her jeans as "bell-bottom" but she does have long hair, and there is a scene in a diner with a sandwich around 17 minutes in.

Comment: Nice... This movie is adorable!